# Z-Index in GeoJSON features using leaflet

Tags: web-mapping, leaflet, geojson, features, z-index

I have a watershed polygon with sub-watersheds contained within the larger watershed. I would like the sub-watersheds drawn on top.

Can i control the drawing order of features within a geojson object or do i have to add the features separately and then control the layer drawing order?

I'm using leaflet 0.7.2

Comment: It is better to use layer drawing order.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use    layer.bringToFront()    and    layer.bringToBack()    methods of leaflet.
See the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-bringtofront)  here.